# How to implement a constantly active loop to check for changes?

Tags: loops, user-interface, intellij-idea, javafx

I created an empty TextField `test` and an empty TextField `test2` in the "start" method

`public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {}`

Now I want to check constantly if `test.getText().equals("")`. If so, `test2.setEditable(false)`, otherwise `test2.setEditable(true)`.

I don't know how to implement it, as it needs to get checked constantly.

I already tried to implement an if-Statement in the `start` method and it actually set `test2` on `notEditable` at the beginning, as`test` is empty but when `test.getText().equals("")` changed to `!test.getText().equals("")` `test2` was still not editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by binding the `editable` property of `test2` to the `text` property of `test`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField test = new TextField();
    TextField test2 = new TextField();

    // do the binding
    test2.editableProperty().bind(test.textProperty().isEmpty().not());

    VBox root = new VBox(20, test, test2);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(50));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 150));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Example");
    primaryStage.show();
  }


}
```

The `text` property of `TextField` is a `StringProperty`. This class has the method `isEmpty` (inherited by `StringExpression`) that returns a `BooleanBinding` that will hold `true` if the `StringProperty`'s value is empty or null. The `not()` call negates the value of the `BooleanBinding` which means `test2` will only be editable if `test`'s text is *not* empty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking all the time you can just listen on changes like this:

```
test.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
  if (newValue.equals("")) {
     test2.setEditable(false);
  } 

);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked !!

Comment: Great! You can mark the answer as the correct one then :)

Comment: I believe, based on OP's question, you also have to set the editability of `test2` to `true` if the new value _doesn't_ equal `""`. Something like: `test.textProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> test2.setEditable(nv != null && !nv.isEmpty()));`.